# Native iPhone Image Filter for Android and Web

Tags: ios, iphone, imagefilter

Does anyone know of a library that replicates the native image filters from the iPhone? For consistency reasons we'd like to use them on our Android and web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Aviary SDK` for filters.

> The Aviary SDK is now the Image Editing component in the Adobe
>   Creative SDK. Visit CreativeSDK.com to access the latest Image Editing
>   SDK and brand new SDK components by Adobe, offering features like
>   store to Creative Cloud and publish to Behance.

Its easy to implement and it is compatible for all platform.android ,ios and web.

So its better to you [aviary sdk](https://developers.aviary.com/) for filters